# Why wasn't Appare Vestigium used in the Harry Potter book series?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

Appare Vestigium is the incantation of a tracking spell that illuminates the area it is being used in a swirl of gold that reveals recent magical activity.

This could have been used many times in the Harry Potter series, namely when the Philosopher's Stone was stolen, to see who stole it, the culprit behind the petrification of Mrs. Norris, Colin Creevey, and Hermione, and in the Goblet of Fire, to see who put the name in the Goblet of Fire, and to see who cursed Katie Bell.

HERE are the BIGGEST ONES!

The years that Voldemort, then Tom Riddle, attended Hogwarts after those nasty incidents.

The houses of Death Eaters when they were arrested following the end of the First Wizarding War. This would have revealed lots of information as well as maybe leads, such as Lucius Malfoy, on the then-current whereabouts of Voldemort.

The return of Voldemort. Dumbledore and, to conclusively convince the entire Wizarding World, Ministry officials could have gone to Little Hangleton to check on what happened between Cedric, Harry, Peter Pettigrew, Voldemort and the 30 Death Eaters (2 and 1/2 Death Eaters in the Goblet of Fire novel = 2.5 * 12 = 30).

Why wasn't Appare Vestigium used by Dumbledore and the other high-ranking Ministry members?

Newt was a student of Dumbledore, who he remained very close to even after expulsion (Dumbledore vouched for him to stay in Hogwarts) and brother of Theseus, a well-respected Auror. Aurors are hired by the Ministry, so Theseus must have known this spell as well, or at least, likely to have known it.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "because it was invented for *Crimes of Grindelwald* and JK Rowling hadn't thought of it when she wrote the books" but I expect that's not the answer you're looking for.

Comment: The philosopher's stone wasn't stolen.

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/207852/100430) argues that it *was* used.

Answer (score 4):

## It may be a specialized spell Newt uses.

As the Fantastic Beasts series is still in progress, new information may be added to the franchise either invalidating or further validating this theory. However, so far in the series *Appare Vestigium* is only cast once, by Newt.

> “*NEWT leads JACOB through the statue and into Magical Paris. He puts his case down and points his wand at the street.*
>
> **NEWT**
>
> *Appare vestigium.*
>
> *The tracking spell materializes as a swirl of gold, which illuminates traces of recent magical activity in the square.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

In addition to being able to track people, *Appare Vestigium* can also be used to track creatures, something Newt would almost certainly have to do quite often as a Magizoologist.

> “*NEWT climbs onto the case and inspects impressions of creatures revealed in the air, while the now-trained adult Niffler sniffs out clues.*
>
> **NEWT**
>
> That’s a Kappa. That’s a Japanese water demon—
>
> *The Niffler sniffs around some shimmering footsteps. The Niffler has found the place where TINA stood in front of the Zouwu.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald (The Original Screenplay)*</sup></sub>

Eddie Redmayne mentioned in an interview that Newt has a very specific skill set, and captured Grindelwald using a spell that Dumbledore would not think to use. Similarly, his tracking spell may not be one that it would occur to Dumbledore or other wizards to use.

> Eddie: I think that what I love about Newt is that he’s not the greatest wizard in the world, but his skill set is so specific. I mean, Tina and Newt call Grindelwald at the end of the last film using a distraction technique – had to see this one – and the sort of lasso [pronounced “lay-sew”] that Dumbledore wouldn’t have thought to use.
>
> Katherine: That’s lasso [pronounced “lah-so”] in our country.
>
> [Everyone laughs]
>
> Eddie: Magical lasso. [laughs] 
> <sub><sup>*[- Eddie Redmayne and Katherine Waterston “Crimes of Grindelwald” Roundtable Interview](http://www.mugglenet.com/2018/11/eddie-redmayne-and-katherine-waterston-crimes-of-grindelwald-roundtable-interview/)*</sup></sub>

It is quite possible that *Appare Vestigium* is a spell that Newt with his specific skills would think to use, but others like Dumbledore and Ministry wizards would not think of it.

Comment: Those films aren't Harry Potter canon IMO. I wish it was actually *about* fantastic beasts, and not a load of rubbish about Nagini and Dumbledore's impossible brother.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I fully agree - my answer is an attempt to make information given in Fantastic Beasts make some sort of sense in the established Harry Potter universe. However, many pieces of it simply do not.

Comment: It seems like quite a stretch to say people knew about this spell but never thought to use it, when it would be perfectly suited to so many situations.

Comment: @Alex It *also* seems like quite a stretch that McGonagall was teaching at Hogwarts since Newt’s school years, and that Voldemort’s snake was once a human woman. This is an in-universe explanation attempting to piece this information into the existing Harry Potter world, when the out-of-universe explanation is likely that the addition of this spell was poorly thought out.

Comment: According to JKR _before_ Fantastic Beasts, McGonagall wouldn't have been a teacher when Newt was at school. They are just retconning some characters to give it a semblance of familiarity (and on that note, how does a suit-wearing suave Dumbledore turn into robe-wearing crazy Dumbledore who is obsessed with socks?)