# What extra protection did Voldemort gain using Harry's blood

Tags: harry-potter

When Lily gave her life for Harry she protected Harry and this is why Voldemort couldn't kill him. But what extra protection came about when Voldemort used Harry's blood to regain a body, and what protection still would have remained if any, if Voldemort had not used Harry's blood?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Lily's enchantments work for Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32157/why-did-lilys-enchantments-work-for-voldemort)

Comment: sorry, that didn't really what the explicit difference was when harry's blood was put in Voldemort as compared to the sole effect of lily's enchantment (before Voldemort used Harry's blood)

Comment: Hi Pat, the only protection that Voldemort gets from using Harry's blood is that he can harm Harry freely. If he had used someone else's blood, he wouldn't have gained that benefit (And that's why he wanted Harry's blood specifically). There are no other protections that Voldemort gets, although there is a protection to Harry that backfires on Voldemort later in the series, as mentioned in the linked question.